# How to run a Parse cloud job in batches of users to avoid time limit?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm currently running the following Parse cloud code job which iterates through every user in the database, and I'm starting to hit the 15 minute time limit. How can I set this to run in batches of 500 users at a time instead of all users at once? I would need it to run through the users in order, so user 1-500 for the first batch, then 500-1000 for the 2nd batch, and so on, that way it doesn't repeat anyone.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("MCBackground", function(request, status) {
    // ... other code to setup usersQuery ...
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    var usersQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

    return usersQuery.each(function(user) {
            return processUser(user)
                .then(function(eBayResults) {
                    return mcComparison(user, eBayResults);
                });
        })
        .then(function() {
            // Set the job's success status
            status.success("MCBackground completed successfully.");
        }, function(error) {
            // Set the job's error status
            status.error("Got an error " + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
});
```

Comment: Depending on your use case, maybe there are other solutions to this. Can you explain what this job is doing so we might easier think outside your current thoughts?

Comment: @Handsomeguy It queries parse for all user objects. For every user object with a matchCenterItem object as its child, it pings ebays API with the matchCenterItem properties as parameters. It then compares ebay's response with that users mComparisonArray object, if they're different, it updates it with the response. I left a bunch out, but that's the general gist. It essentially iterates through every matchCenterItem of every user and updates things.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, from your comment I see you have a constraint you can add: only query for user objects that has a matchCenterItem:

```
query.exist("matchCenterItem");
```

I don't know how many percent of your users would *not* have this field, but maybe you already now will have reduced the number of Users to fetch.

I have no idea how often this job is run or what you are comparing with, but how likely is it that this data will change? Do you always need to run it on ALL users, or can you set a flag so that you don't run it on the same user again? At all, or until some time has passed?